# Как запустить оконный менеджер GNOME?

Tags: gnome, linux

Как обычно я выполнил обновления программ через менеджер обновлений. Перезагрузил комп и у меня не отображается верхняя планка над каждым окошком, с помощью которой можно передвинуть окно, свернуть, закрыть или расширить. Полазив по настройкам, я понял, что не запущен какой-то оконный менеджер.

В консоли я запускал startx и xinit, но они оба ответили "user not authorized to run the X server, aborting".

В общем, не знаю как быть, окошки маленькие, я еле втиснул своё сообщение сюда. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какой линукс, какая версия?

Comment: тебе нужно запустить `metacity`, если это gnome 2

Comment: Возможно отвалился compiz. Он является декоратором окон, т.е. именно он отрисовывает title bar окон и пр. вещи. Но без него система функциональна и графический режим работает. Мне помогало отключение-включение эффектов рабочего стола

Comment: помогло решение с metacity, но вот не порядок, удаляю консоль и все возвращается на прежние места.
у меня убунту 10.10
я работаю с нетбука, и визуальные эффекты на нем неприменимы. а что за именно эффекты рабочего стола?

Comment: Как ты запускал metacity, из gnome-terminal? и какой командой?

Comment: открываю консоль и пишу metacity и жму ентер

Comment: ну быстрофикс чтобы не закрывалось: `(metacity&)` хотя решать это надо по-другому, смотреть где ошибка

Comment: вобщем, вышло новое обновление и проблема отпала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй запустить так:

```
nohup metacity
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, startx надо выполнять от имени суперпользователя (root). А во-вторых, раз у вас не голая консоль, а какие-то окна все-таки есть, скорее всего Х-то у вас как раз запущены, а вот GDM почему-то не запустился. Попробуйте так:

```
sudo killall Xorg gdm  
sudo gdm
```

Comment: Выполнил и результат:

** (gdm-binary:3055): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager

** (gdm-binary:3055): WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out

т.е. тоже само осталось